# Is it possible to connect android apps and desktop apps into same database?Then Which database i want to do it simple?

Tags: android, database, connection, desktop

I am doing my college project. I want to `connect desktop apps and android apps` designed by my team to connect a common database. I am confused with database. I want to choose do it in a simple way.

Comment: In which technology you will make Desktop App?

Comment: front end java swing,awt,windows builder. backend is confusing me.